# PowerDNS Recursor - allow-from-file issue

Tags: powerdns-recursor

I have just installed PowerDNS Recursor v4.4.2 on Debian 11.

Now I like to whitelist some subnets by using the **allow-from-file**=/etc/pdns/recursor.d/acl.conf directive in recursor.conf.

The acl.conf file looks like this:

```
allow-from=10.0.0.0/8
allow-from=172.16.0.0/12
allow-from=198.168.0.0/16
```

Unfortunately this leads to the following error popup in syslog:

```
pdns_recursor[99845]: Exception: Unable to convert 'allow-from=10.0.0.0' to a netmask
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Tnx, John